# DotNet.Highcharts ChartTypes reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

I am trying to add to my web application Highcharts. In my Controller I have

```
using DotNet.Highcharts;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
```

and Action

```
public ActionResult Chart()
    {
        DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart").SetTitle(new Title()
        {
            Text = "Porównanie prędkości poszczególnych technologii"
        }).SetXAxis(new XAxis
        {
            Categories = new[] { "GPRS", "EDGE", "UMTS", "CDMA", "HSPA", "HSPA+", "LTE" }
        }).SetSeries(new Series
        {
            Type = ChartTypes.Column, Name = "Prędkość", Data = new Data(new object[] { 0.08, 0.3, 2, 9.3, 14.4, 42, 150 })
        });

        return View(chart);
    }
```

But I have error, that tells me the ChartTypes does not exists in current context. What should I do? Am I missing some reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this reference:

```
using DotNet.Highcharts.Enums;
```

Or use the fully qualified name:

```
DotNet.Highcharts.Enums.ChartTypes.Column
```